# What is the incentive for people who provide us ETH for testing?

Tags: ether, testnets

this is not a technical question, however I was curious to know what is the incentive for people who provide us ETH for testing? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Testing blockchains were created for testing purposes so the coins are worthless by design.

PoA networks like Rinkeby, Goerli, Kovan the funds were allocated to respectable members with the explicit purpose of giving away funds for other projects testing needs.

PoW networks like Ropsten anyone can mine, some people will mine for they own projects (software or hardware). Then give away the unused eth. Some miners are managed by the community for the explicit purpose of keep the network running.